# Slicing out string (unaligned sequence)

Tags: python, string, list, function, slice

I'm having trouble figuring out how to extract a certain string from input 2 using the numbers in input 1. I'm trying to extract all the bases in the dna/query sequence that are NOT aligned in the subject ID FO203509.1. So everything from 1057-2381 essentially when you look at the blast file input 1. q.start is where the sequence starts in the query sequence file input2 and q.end is where it ends.

Input 1: Blast report file (sorry I couldn't copy and paste-formatting was all wrong)

[image]

Input 2: query sequence file

emb|AJ000012.1| Mycobacterium tuberculosis recA gene (strain Canetti)
CGAAAGGTCAGATCCGGGCCGGTGAGCACGCCGGATCCGGCCAGGCTAGCGGTGTTCAGCAGATCGTCGG
TGATCCGGACCAGCCGCGCACGCAAGTCGGGCCGCACCGCCGCCAGGGCGTTCGACGCGCCGACGAGCGC
GGACGCGATGTTGCCACACGCGGCGTGTCACACTTGAATCGAACAGGTGTTCGGCTACTGTGGTGATCAT
TCGGAGCAGCCGACTTGTCAGTGGCTGTCTCTAGTGTCACGGCCAACCGACCGATACCGGTCAATCGAAC
ACCGACCACAGGAGAGGCACCATGACGCAGACCCCCGATCGGGAAAAGGCGCTCGAGCTGGCAGTGGCCC
AGATCGAGAAGAGTTACGGCAAAGGTTCGGTGATGCGCCTCGGCGACGAGGCGCGTCAGCCGATTTCGGT
CATTCCGACCGGATCCATCGCACTCGACGTGGCCCTGGGCATTGGCGGCCTGCCGCGTGGCCGGGTGATA
GAGATATACGGCCCGGAATCTTCGGGTAAGACCACCGTGGCGCTGCACGCGGTGGCCAACGCTCAGGCCG
CCGGTGGTGTTGCGGCGTTCATCGACGCCGAGCACGCGCTGGATCCGGACTATGCCAAGAAGCTCGGTGT
CGACACCGATTCGCTGCTGGTCAGCCAGCCGGACACCGGGGAACAGGCACTCGAGATCGCCGACATGCTG
ATCCGCTCGGGTGCGCTTGACATCGTGGTGATCGACTCGGTGGCGGCGCTGGTGCCGCGCGCGGAGCTCG
AAGGCGAGATGGGCGACAGCCACGTCGGGCTGCAGGCCCGGCTGATGAGCCAGGCGCTGCGGAAAATGAC
CGGCGCGCTGAATAATTCGGGCACCACGGCGATCTTCATCAACCAGCTCCGCGACAAGATCGGAGTGATG
TTCGGGTCGCCCGAGACGACAACGGGCGGAAAGGCGTTGAAGTTCTACGCGTCGGTGCGCATGGACGTGC
GGCGGGTCGAGACGCTCAAGGACGGTACCAACGCGGTCGGCAACCGCACCCGGGTCAAGGTCGTCAAGAA
CAAGTGCCTCGCAGAGGGCACTCGGATCTTCGATCCGGTCACCGGTACAACGCATCGCATCGAGGATGTT
GTCGATGGGCGCAAGCCTATTCATGTCGTGGCTGCCGCCAAGGACGGAACGCTGCATGCGCGGCCCGTGG
TGTCCTGGTTCGACCAGGGAACGCAGGATGTGATCGGGTTGCGGATCGCCGGTGGCGCCATCGTGTGGGC
GACACCCGATCACAAGGTGCTGACAGAGTACGGCTGGCGTGCCGCCGGGGAACTCCGCAAGGGAGACCGG
GTGGCGCAACCGCGACGCTTCGACGGATTCGGTGACAGTGCGCCGATTCCGGCGGATCATGCCCGGCTGC
TTGGCTACCTGATCGGAGATGGCAGGGATGGTTGGGTGGGGGGCAAGACTCCGATCAACTTCATCAATGT
TCAGCGGGCGCTCATTGACGACGTGACGCGAATCGCTGCGACGCTCGGTTGTGCGGCCCATCCGCAGGGG
CGTATCTCACTCGCGATCGCTCATCGACCCGGTGAGCGCAACGGGGTACTGGACCTTTGTCGGCGGGCCG
GTGTGCACGGCAAGCTCGCGTGGGAGAAGACGATTCCGAATTGGTTCTTCGAGCCGGACATCGCGGCCGA
CATTGTCGGCAATCTGCTCTTCGGCCTGTTCGAAAGCGACGGGTGGGTGAGCCGGGAACAGACCGGGGCA
CTTCGGGTCGGTTACACGACGACCTCTGAACAACTCGCGCATCAGATTCATTGGCTGCTGCTGCGGTTCG
GTGTCGGGAGCACCGTTCGAGATTACGATCCGACCCAGAAGCGGCCGAGCATCGTCAACGGTCGACGGAT
CCAGAGCAAACGTCAAGTGTTCGAGGTCCGGATCTCGGGTATGGATAACGTCACGGCATTCGCGGAGTCA
GTTCCCATGTGGGGGCCGCGCGGTGCCGCGCTTATCCAGGCGATTCCAGAAGCCACGCAGGGGCGGCGTC
GTGGATCGCAAGCGACATATCTGGCTGCAGAGATGACCGATGCCGTGCTGAATTATCTGGACGAGCGCGG
CGTGACCGCGCAGGAGGCCGCGGCCATGATCGGTGTAGCTTCCGGGGACCCCCGCGGTGGAATGAAGCAG
GTCTTAGGTGCCAGCCGCCTTCGTCGGGATCGCGTGCAGGCGCTCGCGGATGCCCTGGATGACAAATTCC
TGCACGACATGCTGGCGGAAGAACTCCGGTATTCGGTGATCCGAGAAGTGCTGCCAACGCGGCGGGCACG
AACGTTCGACCTCGAGGTCGAGGAACTGCACACCCTCGTCGCCGAAGGGGTTGTCGTGCACAACTGTTCG
CCCCCCTTCAAGCAGGCCGAGTTCGACATCCTCTACGGCAAGGGAATCAGCAGGGAGGGCTCGCTGATCG
ACATGGGTGTGGATCAGGGCCTCATCCGCAAGTCGGGTGCCTGGTTCACCTACGAGGGCGAGCAGCTCGG
CCAGGGCAAGGAGAATGCCCGCAACTTCTTGGTGGAGAACGCCGACGTGGCTGACGAGATCGAGAAGAAG
ATCAAGGAAAAGCTTGGCATTGGTGCCGTGGTGACCGATGACCCCTCAAATGACGGTGTCCTGCCCGCCC
CCGTCGACTTCTGAGCGCGAAGAGCAGGCGCGGGCACTGTGCCTGCGCCTGCTCACCGCGCGATCCCGCA
CCCGCGC

My code:

```
input_1=open('blastreport', 'r')
input_2=open('queryseq', 'r')

def slice_sequence(input1,input2):
    for line in input1:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            list = line.split()
            q_start=int(list[6])
            q_end=int(list[7])
            if list[1]=='FO203509.1':
                for line in input2:
                    next(input2)
                    string=''.join(row.strip() for row in input2)
                    answer=string[q_end:]+string[:q_start]
     return answer

ans=slice_sequence(input_1, input_2)
print(ans)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the second for loop where you iterate over the input2, are you trying to join all the lines into one line and get the expected slice from the one line? If that is the case, you don't need a loop. You can simply do,

```
string = ''.join(row.strip() for row in input2[1:])
answer = string[q_end:]+string[:q_start]
return answer
```